# how to call Synchronous function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect

i have created one global function for fetching records from database mysql , but its return undefined
but once we pass static data under this function its working fine ,

```
   methods.trendingPodData =   function (){
    var sql = "SELECT * from table1 where 1";
      con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(result);
        var hashtagsArray = JSON.parse(myJSON);
         //console.log(hashtagsArray);
         return hashtagsArray;      
   }); 
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is an asynchronous operation, not a synchronous operation.  So, your title is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create promise and while calling function resolve it,

```
 methods.trendingPodData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var sql = "SELECT * from table1 where 1";
      con.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
        if(err) {
         return reject(err)
        }
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(result);
        var hashtagsArray = JSON.parse(myJSON);
         //console.log(hashtagsArray);
         resolve(hashtagsArray);      
   }); 
 }
}
```

And while calling function,

```
router.get('/GetPodHomeScreen', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const allTrendingDataArray1 = await globalVar.data.trendingPodData(); 
  res.send(allTrendingDataArray1)
 } catch(error) {
  res.status(500).send(error)
 }
})
```

Comment: Can you let me know how to create promise?

Comment: Please check code from answer

Comment: ok i am calling like this

Comment: AllTrendingDataArray1 = globalVar.data.trendingPodData();

Comment: You are familiar with async/await?

Comment: No Sir i am not

Comment: i am new in node js

Comment: Please check for promisification section in JavaScript

Comment: as you modified function there is no return type so how can i got result AllTrendingDataArray1 = globalVar.data.trendingPodData();

Comment: Please share function where you are calling, ```AllTrendingDataArray1 = globalVar.data.trendingPodData(); ```

Comment: router.get('/GetPodHomeScreen', function (req, res) {   AllTrendingDataArray1 = globalVar.data.trendingPodData(); }

Comment: i am creating API , here created one function and fetching data for same function as i have shared you already

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: once i have updated , getting this error

Comment: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yes, ```async (req, res) => {``` it has async there

Comment: Yes Now working Vikas Sir Thanks

Comment: Accept it as answer